# PHPinfo returns blank page

Tags: php, installation

I am totally new to programming.. Was installing the wampserver.. I'm using windows, and I have a file called test.php inside the folder C:\wamp\www . Inside the test.php file, I have this code

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Then I opened the firefox browser and then entered the statement below but it returns a blank page. Is the url below right? 
http://localhost/www/test.php

Am I doing the right thing? Tried using the search function but couldn't get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, the code is missing above.. I had this code inside the test.php

Answer (score 4):

Your URL should be http://localhost/test.php

The "www" folder is your DocumentRoot folder by default. The URL http://localhost/ will point to that folder. Everything after that works like a normal document path.

Answer (score 1):

A blank page means that an error occurred before output began, and you have error display disabled. Check your web server error log.